# changing route in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am doing a simple signin/signup using angularjs using ui.router.

signin route is: 
common/signin

signup route is:
common/signup

code for 'common' state:

```
    $stateProvider.state('common',{
    url:'/common',
    templateUrl:'templates/common.html',
    abstract:true,
    resolve:{

            //if acces token is found in local storage then change route to portal/dashboard

            //else continue to common/signin or common/signup

    }

});
```

Is there a way to change routes inside a resolve.
I know this can be done in controller of sign in and sign up.
ie:
I would check in controller for sign :

```
 app.controller('signinController',['tokenService','$scope','$state',function(tokenService,$scope,$state){
    if(tokenService.getToken()!=null){
        $state.go('portal.dashboard');
    }


}]);
```

and the same task is to be done in signup controller.

```
app.controller('signupController',['tokenService','$scope','$state',function(tokenService,$scope,$state){
    if(tokenService.getToken()!=null){
        $state.go('portal.dashboard');
    }


}]);
```

But it will be a duplicate code and I always question myself before doing duplication.
And also doing this flashes the signin or signup template and then shows dashboard.

So I was thinking about a way to check the same while routing in common state.
Is there a way to do this through a service such that I can do:

```
if(token found in local storage){
     $q.reject();
    $state.go('portal.dashboard')
}
else{
    $q.resolve();
    //continue to do /signup or /signin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can inject $timeout

```
$stateProvider.state('common',{
url:'/common',
templateUrl:'templates/common.html',
abstract:true,
resolve:{
   auth:function($timeout,$state,$q){
      if(token found in local storage){
          $timeout(function(){
             $state.go('dashboard')
          })
          return $q.reject();
      }
      else{
        return $q.resolve(token);
      }

   }
}
```

});

something like this will work

Comment: $q.resolve(token) is not changing route to /signin or /signup.It goes to portal/dashboard.

Comment: code inside if(token found in local storage) is working perfectly but the else part does not work as expected.

Comment: i assumed that common state would take you to login if instead it takes you dashboard then revert the login and fail the resolve if token does not exists and redirect to login page

Comment: How to decide whether next state should be signin or signup.You are saying "redirect to login page ".How to decide this step.

Comment: thats a hole different question and is up to your business logic

Comment: If the route is common/signin then common should resolve to signin and common/signup should resolve to signup and both should reject to portal.dashboard.Your answer is  close.please help.

Comment: how where you planing on differentiating signin/signup in your controller? or you don't know how to do so?

Comment: you do that and while you do it you'll figure out how to do it your self

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon `$timeout` works perfectly. However, why is `$timeout` necessary? After all we do reject the promise in resolve?

Comment: the problem is that you have to give time for the $digest cycle to process  the rejected promise and then tell the router to move on to the next state

Answer (score 0):

You are using states, so I would use

$state.go(state);

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

If you want to have multiple child states of your common state, you can look into using nested states:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views